# Remove unnecessary values - scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
onclick="try{appendPropertyPosition(this,'B10016735','9176967671, 9176964646, 8939721171','44-22583703','Dealer','manesh');jsb9onUnloadTracking();jsevt.stopBubble(event);}catch(e){};"
```

Like this there are many `onclick` attributes in the HTML page.

From the above `onclick` attribute using this code

```
join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else '')))
```

I am scraping values as this:

```
B10016735,9176967671, 9176964646, 8939721171,44-22583703,Dealer,manesh
```

But I just want to have one phone number and remove the rest three phone numbers and should look like the following

```
 B10016735,9176967671,Dealer,manesh
```

**Update**

Thing is, the following pattern does not repeat for all the rows in the HTML page
. Few rows have three phonenos, few has two. and sometime zero phone numbers. So the number of phone number varies.

B10016735,9176967671, 9176964646, 8939721171,44-22583703,Dealer,manesh

Answer (score 2):

Given the string

```
In [101]: text = 'B10016735,9176967671, 9176964646, 8939721171,44-22583703,Dealer,manesh'
```

You could split the `text` into pieces with:

```
In [102]: items = [item.strip() for item in text.split(',')]
```

Select the first two items, and the last two items with:

```
In [103]: items[:2]+items[-2:]
Out[103]: ['B10016735', '9176967671', 'Dealer', 'manesh']
```

and form the desired string with:

```
In [104]: ','.join(items[:2]+items[-2:])
Out[104]: 'B10016735,9176967671,Dealer,manesh'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = 'B10016735,9176967671, 9176964646, 8939721171,44-22583703,Dealer,manesh'
>>> re.sub(r'([^,]+,[^,]+,)(.*?)([A-Za-z].*)', r'\1\3', strs)
'B10016735,9176967671,Dealer,manesh'
```

Comment: No. It takes off all the phone numbers. and gives `B10016735,,Dealer,manesh` . Would you mind to see what my whole output is?

Comment: @Venky Please post those testcases and expected output in the question  body.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37492/discussion-between-venky-and-ashwini-chaudhary)